# can not start mysql service in centos 7

Tags: mysql

i tried to start the mysql service but it's not work.

while i use this command

```
service start mysql
```

this error happens!

```
The service command supports only basic LSB actions (start, stop, restart, try-restart, reload, force-reload, status). For other actions, please try to use systemctl.
```

but when i tried to use systemctl it's still not work

```
[root@master-1 ~]# systemctl start mysql
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit not found.
[root@master-1 ~]# systemctl start mysqld
Failed to start mysqld.service: Unit not found.
[root@master-1 ~]#
```

this is the result for systemctl status mysqld mysql

```
● mysqld.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-07-12 10:01:13 WIB; 1 weeks 1 days ago
 Main PID: 872 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Data Dictionary upgrade from MySQL 5.7 in progress"

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
● mysql.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-07-16 17:13:43 WIB; 3 days ago

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

i still don't know what happen

Comment: is mysql installed in ur system?

Comment: I think there is a giveaway as to what's happening in the error messages: `Status: "Data Dictionary upgrade from MySQL 5.7 in progress"`

Answer (score 0):

Hello systemctl works in Ubuntu Os, Not in CentOS.

please use [**/etc/init.d/mysqld restart, /etc/init.d/mysqld start, /etc/init.d/mysqld stop**] instead of systemctl start mysql